# Поставщик 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу подключить базу данных Access к программе через Обозреватель серверов. Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable установлен. Версия Access 2016. Windows 10

Comment: 2010 - это что-то очень старое? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649413/12888024

Comment: Ничего не помогает(

Comment: У вас Windows 10? Судя по https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=10910, "требования к системе", там ничего не написано про Windows 10. Самая новая из всех поддерживаемых - Windows 8

Comment: Да стоит Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

А разрядность офиса и приложения совпадает? Если не совпадает, то не подключишься. Приходилось добавлять в проект специальное 32-разрядное приложение, чтобы оно работало с Акцессом

Comment: Да всё работает, спасибо